# How to inject API server URL when deploying react frontend?

Tags: reactjs, npm

*Disclaimer*: I am a React noob so perhaps what I am trying to do is not the *React Way*

I am writing a React front-end that will be deployed to be served statically by some cloud provider, e.g. S3 or Google Storage or whatever. This front-end interacts with several API servers that live somewhere in the cloud, maybe in the same provider, maybe not. Furthermore, while developing the UI or part of it, those servers' addresses might be local or testing instances.

How do I inject the API server(s) URLs into my react application in a flexible so that I can deploy in dev, staging or prod using different addresses?

**SOLUTION**: I finally ended up using a combination of solutions proposed:

- use `.env.production` and `.env.development` files (exact names) to store the variable `REACT_APP_API_URI = 'host'`
- this is automatically picked-up by create-react-app's build scaffolding and available in UI code as `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI`

Note this somewhat goes against principles from [12 Factor Apps](https://12factor.net/config), e.g. storing env variables in files in version control but it does the job ATM.

Comment: I usually add a `.env.sample` to the repo not the actual files with values. Also, you can probably set that environment variable in your CI/CD to better align with the 12 Factor approach.

Comment: Nice solution. You can use `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` and  `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI)` to watch from any place after adding `.env.production` and `.env.development` files to root dir.

Comment: Important note: With `create-react-app`, you need to prefix `REACT_APP_` to the variable name to be able to access it.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your app for the var to take effect, Ctrl-C to `Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y`, then `npm start`.  I couldn't figure out for the life of me what I was missing

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
// http.js
const getBaseUrl = () => {
  let url;
  switch(process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'production':
      url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
      break;
    case 'development':
    default:
      url = 'https://google.com';
  }

  return url;
}

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: getBaseUrl(),
});
```

Comment: you can see the example here https://github.com/gianglevan94/auto-shop/blob/master/resources/assets/js/config/const.js

Comment: but `process.env.NODE_ENV` assumes there is a node server runninng, isn't it? Which means this works at runtime, not at build time.

Comment: So you mean webpack introspects the JS code and statically replaces those variables with their value?

Comment: Yes. I bet you use create-react-app. When you deploy it as production, you will build the bundle, and NODE_ENV will set to 'production' and your api url will be https://stackoverflow.com/ instead of  https://google.com

Comment: @GiangLe you did not mention which file we need to have the content of your answer

Answer (score 4):

Using this package https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd you could create an env file for your environment

for example create .env.staging and .env file with this code

```
// .env.staging file   
API_URL=https://staging.url.com/api/
```

```
// .env file
API_URL=https://url.com/api/
```

How to fetch with API_URL from env variable:

```
fetch(process.env.API_URL)
```

Then you can just add some extra scripts in your package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:staging": "env-cmd .env.staging yarn build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd .env yarn build"
  }
}
```

Comment: But the `.env` file is read at runtime? When is the `process.env.API_URL` variable defined? I want this to happen at build/deploy time so that when the app executes in the browser it is statically configured with the right URL.

Comment: No, it will transform `process.env.API_URL` when you run a command that include it. For example if you run command `yarn build:staging` to build react, it will transform `fetch(process.env.API_URL)` to `fetch('https://staging.url.com/api/')` and then you can deploy build files to the staging server.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.env` file if the API's are constant for `development` or `production` environment. after `build` you can't change these parameters.

If you want to change the `URL` after build, add a `js` file lets say `config.js`

Include the `conf.js` in `index.html`

Add `URL` in `conf.js` like

```
var URL1 = 'https://www.google.com'
```

You can access the parameter like :

```
export const {URL1} = window;
```

Comment: But f we do this, then URL1 will be publicly available. Anyone can see it.

Comment: Yes, Its not a good practice. There must be a back end server which hosts reactjs app. So that you can hit the server using route name, not using ip and port, IP, port will be same as reactjs apps. Then you can get the data from your desired applications from the server side.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that making use of environment variables on the build step for example.

You can use something like [.env](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) that allows you to define environment variables and load them on your webpack file for example (assuming you use webpack). But you can really use it with any bundler.

.env file:

```
API=http://localhost:3000
```

On your webpack you could make use of the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

example taken from docs: add your API env

```
    ...
    require('dotenv').config()
    ...

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      API_ENDPOINT: process.env.API,
      PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
      VERSION: JSON.stringify('5fa3b9'),
      BROWSER_SUPPORTS_HTML5: true,
      TWO: '1+1',
      'typeof window': JSON.stringify('object')
    });
```

Anyway, this is just one way. I like this way because it makes my project ready for defining API keys and other useful stuff for different environments.

**NOTE: You can even define different .env files for local, staging and production and load the respective one in the webpack depending on the build type.**

Comment: This makes sense but I have used  `create-react-app` to scaffold my application and it does not _seem_ to use webpack. Or is it using it under the hood?

Comment: @insitu yes it does use webpack under the hood. it uses react-scripts.

Comment: @insitu look at this post: https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d 

it is basically my approach and uses CRA

Comment: This is confusing: Are `process.env.XXX` available at build-time?

Answer (score 0):

After creating the .env file. Please restart the app. Like in reactJs use `npm start` command to restart it. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

in the app.js file
you can create function of this type
sessionStorage.setItem("apipathurl","http://localhost:3000/api")

```
sessionStorage.setItem("apipathurl","https://example.onrender.com/api");
```

and call this function each file of your app  as in login.js

const baseURL = sessionStorage.getItem("apipathurl");

call this baseURL into your API endpoint

const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/user/login`, {
method: 'POST',
body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
});

this is the the way to create live url path for your app

Comment: remarks // this is for reactjs and node js